# pdf.js : read file from another server

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I use this pdf.js https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/  library to render pdf files on my own site .. 
everything work fine but when I try to read files from my amazon s3 did not work ?

if I put the pdf file in my server it works fine (assets/books/my.pdf)
but if I put it on another server did not.
for example my file on amazon s3 : 
s3.amazonaws.com/MYBUCKET/MYBOOK.pdf

any ideas ? 
thanks ..

Comment: Cross-domain issues? What do the errors say?

Comment: file on browser couldn't be downloaded , of firebug I saw this error : Error: A Promise can be rejected only once undefined , thanks

Comment: when I open my pdf file from the browser direct works fine , there is no wrong with the link at all ..

Answer (score 1):

I'ts a cross-domain issue with javascript

I did it with mod_rewrite with this simple code :

```
RewriteRule ^MAGIC-FOLDER/(.*)$ http://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/$1 [P]
```

so in my js file I just make the linke like this :

```
MAGIC-FOLDER/MY.PDF
```

he will get the file from amazon s3 :

```
http://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/MY.PDF
```

actually there is no folder in my server with this name "MAGIC-FOLDER"

-_^

Comment: Yes, this sounds like the issue.  See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#wiki-faq-xhr for more info.